# sabre workflow confirmation for booking and getting PNR details

Tags: sabre

I need sabre API workflow according to below functionality:

**Search -> Fare rules -> Check Availability before booking -> Booking -> Ticketing/PNR details -> Cancellation**

As I have checked on the developer portal and sabre workflow, I have found the below APIs for my requirement:

**GetATH** : SessionCreateRQ; mandatory to get security token

**Search** :
1.  BargainFinderMaxRQ

**Fare Rules** :
1.  OTA_AirRulesLLSRQ

**Availability** :
1.  OTA_AirAvailRQ

**Booking** :
1.  EnhancedAirBookRQ
2.  PassengerDetailsRQ

**Issuing Ticket** :
1.  TravelItineraryReadRQ
2.  DesignatePrinterLLSRQ
3.  AirTicketLLSRQ
4.  EndTransactionLLSRQ

**Cancellation** :
1.  AirSeatCancelLLSRQ

**ReleaseATH** : SessionCloseRQ, must to end a transaction/session

Anyone who have done SOAP integration for Sabre API, can confirm if these API's to call in this flow is correct or, or please let me know if any other API available

Answer (score 2):

Search : 1. BargainFinderMaxRQ and Availability : 1. OTA_AirAvailRQ both API are to search the flights with different options and response. And the complete workflow also depends which API you choose to search the fligh.

If you want to search flights using BargainFinderMaxRQ than below can be a flow to issue the ticket

1. Session Create
2. BFM (Search)
3. EnhancedAirBookRQ
4. PassengerDetailsRQ
5. TravelItineraryReadRQ
6. DesignatePrinterLLSRQ
7. AirTicketLLSRQ
8. EndTransactionLLSRQ
9. SessionCloseRQ

if using Availability : 1. OTA_AirAvailRQ :

1. Session Create
2. OTA_AirAvailRQ (Search)
3. ShortSellRQ
4. OTA_AirPriceRQ
5. TravelItineraryReadRQ
6. PassengerDetailsRQ
7. DesignatePrinterLLSRQ
8. TravelItineraryReadRQ
9. AirTicketLLSRQ
10. EndTransactionLLSRQ
11. SessionCloseRQ

Cancellation Flow

1. Session Create
2. TravelItineraryReadRQ
3. OTA_CancelLLSRQ
4. SessionCloseRQ

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks @Sheheryar Aamir

Comment: there is no any test steps for these API's in the SoapUI project that Sabre team has given on developer portal:
1. StructuredFareRulesRQ
2. OTA_AirAvailRQ
3. OTA_CancelRQ

can u please help in this regard, if u having any test-steps for these API's

Comment: can you please explain what you want to achieve with these 
1. StructuredFareRulesRQ
2. OTA_AirAvailRQ
3.     OTA_CancelRQ
what user flow/ business logic you want to create

Comment: I want to create the business logic acc. to this flow :

`Search -> Fare rules -> Check Availability before booking -> Booking -> Ticketing/PNR details -> Cancellation`

I want to use StructuredFareRulesRQ  API to get fare rules for a particular flight on the flight results page for end-user who will be booking the flight.

OTA_AirAvailRQ, I want to call for checking the availability of the flight just before calling the API call sequence to book the flight.

OTA_CancelRQ , for cancellation.

Comment: Search and Check Availability is the same thing 
BFM service is used to search lowest fare. OTA_AirAvailRQ is used to search for flights and the corresponding class availability information.
Once you are done with Search (BFM or AirAvail) and the flight is selected you can call for Fare rules.
Then call EnhancedAirBook (to Book and to price) and after EnhancedAirBook call passengerDetail to complete the booking (in response you will get ItineraryRef ID = PNR Number).

Once PNR is created uou can retrieve it  (TravelItineraryReadRQ) for ticket issue flow or cancellation

Comment: Thanks @Sheheryar Aamir, fr the help

Comment: TravelItineraryRead is being end of lifed, so you should use GetReservation instead